# How to avoid white space between tags in jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to print the content of an html page saving it in a String but jsoup add additional white space

```html
<h1>Title</h1><p>paragraph</p>
```

I want this result :"**Titleparagraph**" but my result is "Title paragraph" how to avoid this?
So WITHOUT the TAGS

```
    File input = new File("/Users/Vincenzo/Desktop/tirocinio/test1/t1.html");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");


     Element allHTML = doc.select("html").first();




    System.out.print(allHTML.text());
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: ok i shared it !